# Direct ABCD matrix calculation from incident and reflected currents and voltages (i.e. obtained by 2 port FDTD simulation results)

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, simulation, scattering

Usual method for transmission (ABCD) matrix construction, from 2 ports EM simulation results, is to first calculate S parameters for each port i.e.:

```
s11 = port{1}.Vref / port{1}.Vinc;
s12 = port{1}.Vref / port{2}.Vinc;
s21 = port{2}.Vref / port{1}.Vinc;
s22 = port{2}.Vref / port{2}.Vinc;
```

Then to forge ABCD matrix from S parameters and Zref (used in EM simulation):

```
A = ((1+s11) * (1-s22) + s12 * s21) / (2*s21);
B = Zref   * ((1+s11) * (1+s22) - s12*s21) / (2*s21);
C = (1 / Zref) * ((1-s11)*(1-s22) - s12*s21) / (2*s21);
D = ((1-s11) * (1+s22) + s12.*s21) / (2*s21);
```

My question is: **Is there direct (one step) way, to calculate ABCD matrix, from EM simulation results,** apart from c/p whole S parameter equations into ABCD calc?

Comment: What parameters are available from your simulation other than S? If Vref and Vinc, why not just substitute into the ABCD formula quoted?

Comment: Simulation (openEMS), natively, provides incident/reflected voltages and currents for given frequency and Zo, per port. S parameters are calculated as stated. I'm already substituting in two steps (S from readings, then conversion to ABCD). Now, I'm looking for more elegant way. I tried that, but my math is not good enough. Couldn't find anything more then just definitions A=V1/V2 (I2==0) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... just doing some algebra on it,

Let: 
`port{1}.Vref` be \$V_{R1}\$ 
`port{2}.Vref` be \$V_{R2}\$ 
`port{1}.Vinc` be \$V_{I1}\$ 
`port{2}.Vinc` be \$V_{I2}\$

Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
s_{11} = \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I1}} & \qquad s_{12} = \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} & \qquad s_{21} = \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} & \qquad s_{22} = \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I2}} \\
\end{eqnarray}

substituting,

\begin{eqnarray}
A =                          \frac{ \left(1 + \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(1 - \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) + \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
B = Z_\textrm{ref}           \frac{ \left(1 + \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(1 + \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) - \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
C = \frac{1}{Z_\textrm{ref}} \frac{ \left(1 - \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(1 - \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) - \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
D =                          \frac{ \left(1 - \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(1 + \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) + \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
\end{eqnarray}

distributing \$V_{I1}\$,

\begin{eqnarray}
A =                          \frac{ \left(\frac{V_{I1} + V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(\frac{V_{I2} - V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) + \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
B = Z_\textrm{ref}           \frac{ \left(\frac{V_{I1} + V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(\frac{V_{I2} + V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) - \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
C = \frac{1}{Z_\textrm{ref}} \frac{ \left(\frac{V_{I1} - V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(\frac{V_{I2} - V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) - \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
D =                          \frac{ \left(\frac{V_{I1} - V_{R1}}{V_{I1}}\right) \left(\frac{V_{I2} + V_{R2}}{V_{I2}}\right) + \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{I2}} \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
\end{eqnarray}

gathering \$V_{I1} V_{I2}\$,

\begin{eqnarray}
A =                          \frac{1}{V_{I1} V_{I2}} \frac{ \left(V_{I1} + V_{R1}\right) \left(V_{I2} - V_{R2}\right) + V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
B = Z_\textrm{ref}           \frac{1}{V_{I1} V_{I2}} \frac{ \left(V_{I1} + V_{R1}\right) \left(V_{I2} + V_{R2}\right) - V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
C = \frac{1}{Z_\textrm{ref}} \frac{1}{V_{I1} V_{I2}} \frac{ \left(V_{I1} - V_{R1}\right) \left(V_{I2} - V_{R2}\right) - V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
D =                          \frac{1}{V_{I1} V_{I2}} \frac{ \left(V_{I1} - V_{R1}\right) \left(V_{I2} + V_{R2}\right) + V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 \frac{V_{R2}}{V_{I1}} } \\
\end{eqnarray}

distribute some more,

\begin{eqnarray}
A = & \dfrac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} + V_{R1} V_{I2} - V_{I1} V_{R2} - V_{R1} V_{R2} + V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
B = Z_\textrm{ref} & \dfrac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} + V_{R1} V_{I2} + V_{I1} V_{R2} + V_{R1} V_{R2} - V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
C = \dfrac{1}{Z_\textrm{ref}} & \dfrac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} - V_{R1} V_{I2} - V_{I1} V_{R2} + V_{R1} V_{R2} - V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
D = & \dfrac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} - V_{R1} V_{I2} + V_{I1} V_{R2} - V_{R1} V_{R2} + V_{R1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
\end{eqnarray}

notice rightmost terms cancel out,

\begin{eqnarray}
A =                          \frac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} + V_{R1} V_{I2} - V_{I1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
B = Z_\textrm{ref}           \frac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} + V_{R1} V_{I2} + V_{I1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
C = \frac{1}{Z_\textrm{ref}} \frac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} - V_{R1} V_{I2} - V_{I1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
D =                          \frac{ V_{I1} V_{I2} - V_{R1} V_{I2} + V_{I1} V_{R2} }{ 2 V_{I2} V_{R2} } \\
\end{eqnarray}

Doesn't seem to be any more useful reduction to be done here.

Comment: Wow, that is really hard work. Just to remind you, if S parameters equations are inserted, when forging ABCD, that different versions of VR1 and VR2 (lets name them VR1s and VR2s ) are used to get s21 and s12. Reason is switching active port side. When port1 is active, s11 and s21 are obtained (using VR1, VI1 and VR2s). When port2 is active, s22 and s12 are obtained (using VR2, VI2 and VR1s).

Comment: I think everything got carried through, so that should be fine. YMMV; I'm just some guy on the internet, remember.

Comment: Great then. I'm going to test it. Thank you very much. BTW, I'm sorry, if I sounded arrogantly, about that port flipping issue. That wasn't my intention.

Comment: Oh no problem, it's a valid concern, I understand. If the equations worked as-is, and I didn't drop anything in the math, I don't see why these won't. But that leaves some gaps, and you'll have to test if it checks out, ultimately.

Comment: Hi Tim, I found solution without explicit use of Zref. Your suggestions are welcome. If you have some time, please check the math?

Comment: @DankoDnevic I'd have to sit down and work it out (also, I don't know exactly what definitions V and I have, so it could be down to some sign errors for example), but it seems reasonable. If you're getting identical results on networks you've measured before, that's -- well, not complete proof of course, but a good sign.

Comment: Yes results are almost identical (FP differences in the range 1e-15). I will edit my post, to add steps I used to get these equations.

Comment: BTW, I'm not that good in math, so I solved and simplified equations using SYMPY and Wolframalpha. That part of proof is missing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that it is somewhat unconventional to respond to one's own query on this platform; however, I deem it important to provide a comprehensive answer for the benefit of future users who may encounter a similar issue. This is by no means intended to undermine the valuable input provided by Tim Williams. In my quest to resolve the aforementioned problem, I focused particularly on scenarios where the reference impedance, Z<sub>ref</sub>, is unequal across both ports. It became evident that employing Mr. Williams' equations directly is unfeasible in such configurations unless one resorts to renormalization. Consequently, my investigation sought a resolution that obviates the explicit dependency on Z<sub>ref</sub>.

First we need to obtain two pass (one for each port active) set of current and voltage parameters, from both ports, which are needed for further calculations:

In pass 1 (Port 1 excite):

```
p1V2 = port{2}.uf.ref; % voltage from Port 2, when Port 1 is excited

p1I2 = port{2}.if.ref; % current from Port 2, when Port 1 is excited

p1V1 = port{1}.uf.tot; % total voltage on Port 1, when Port 1 is excited

p1I1 = port{1}.if.inc - port{1}.if.ref; % current entering the network from P1
```

In pass 2 (Port 2 excite):

```
p2V1 = port{1}.uf.ref; % voltage from Port 1, when Port 2 is excited

p2I1 = port{1}.if.ref; % current from Port 1, when Port 2 is excited

p2V2 = port{2}.uf.tot; % total voltage on Port 2, when Port 2 is excited

p2I2 = port{2}.if.inc - port{2}.if.ref; % current entering the network from P2
```

As ABCD matrix is defined for a two-port network in terms of the total voltages and currents as following:

$$p1V1 =  A \cdot p1V2 + B \cdot p1I2$$
$$p1I1 =  C \cdot p1V2 + D \cdot p1I2$$

and for excitation from Port 2:

$$p2V2 =  D \cdot p2V1 + B \cdot p2I1$$
$$p2I2 = C \cdot p2V1 + A \cdot p2I1$$

Forging ABCD parameters, under condition
$$A \cdot D-B \cdot C = 1$$
is then straightforward, from obtained parameters, by solving system of equations for A, B, C and D:

$$Eq1 = A \cdot p1V2 + B \cdot p1I2 - p1V1 == 0$$
$$Eq2 = C \cdot p1V2 + D \cdot p1I2 - p1I1 == 0$$
$$Eq3 = D \cdot p2V1 + B \cdot p2I1 - p2V2 == 0$$
$$Eq4 = C \cdot p2V1 + A \cdot p2I1 - p2I2 == 0$$
$$Eq5 = A \cdot D-B \cdot C - 1 == 0$$

Using SymPy, we are looking for two solutions:

```
>>> Eq1
A*p1V2 + B*p1I2 - p1V1
>>> Eq2
C*p1V2 + D*p1I2 - p1I1
>>> Eq3
B*p2I1 + D*p2V1 - p2V2
>>> Eq4
A*p2I1 + C*p2V1 - p2I2
>>> Eq5
A*D - B*C - 1

>>> solve([Eq1, Eq2, Eq4, Eq5], [A, B, C, D], dict=True)
[{A: (p1I2*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I2)/(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1), B: (p1I1*p1V1*p2V1 - p1I2*p1V2*p2V1 + p1V1**2*p2I1 - p1V1*p1V2*p2I2)/(p1I2*(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1)), C: (p1I1*p2I2 - p1I2*p2I1)/(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1), D: (p1I1**2*p2V1 + p1I1*p1V1*p2I1 - p1I1*p1V2*p2I2 + p1I2*p1V2*p2I1)/(p1I2*(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1))}]

>>> solve([Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq5], [A, B, C, D], dict=True)
[{A: (p1I1*p1V1*p2V1 - p1I2*p1V1*p2V2 + p1I2*p1V2*p2V1 + p1V1**2*p2I1)/(p1V2*(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1)), B: (p1V1*p2V2 - p1V2*p2V1)/(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1), C: (p1I1**2*p2V1 - p1I1*p1I2*p2V2 + p1I1*p1V1*p2I1 - p1I2*p1V2*p2I1)/(p1V2*(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1)), D: (p1I1*p2V2 + p1V2*p2I1)/(p1I1*p2V1 + p1V1*p2I1)}]
```

Choosing simpler/shorter solutions, we have final solution.
In Matlab/Octave code:

```
A = (p1V1 * p2I2 + p1I2 * p2V1) / (p1I1 * p2V1 + p1V1 * p2I1);

B = (p1V1 * p2V2 - p1V2 * p2V1) / (p1I1 * p2V1 + p1V1 * p2I1);

C = (p1I1 * p2I2 - p1I2 * p2I1) / (p1I1 * p2V1 + p1V1 * p2I1);

D = (p1I1 * p2V2 + p1V2 * p2I1) / (p1I1 * p2V1 + p1V1 * p2I1);
```

As formatted math:

$$ M^{k}_{j}$$

- (M) measured value (V or I)
- (k) excitation port
- (j) meas. port

$$A = \frac{{V^{1}_{1} \cdot I^{2}_{2} + I^{1}_{2} \cdot V^{2}_{1}}}{{I^{1}_{1} \cdot V^{2}_{1} + V^{1}_{1} \cdot I^{2}_{1}}}$$

$$B = \frac{{V^{1}_{1} \cdot V^{2}_{2} - V^{1}_{2} \cdot V^{2}_{1}}}{{I^{1}_{1} \cdot V^{2}_{1} + V^{1}_{1} \cdot I^{2}_{1}}}$$

$$C = \frac{{I^{1}_{1} \cdot I^{2}_{2} - I^{1}_{2} \cdot I^{2}_{1}}}{{I^{1}_{1} \cdot V^{2}_{1} + V^{1}_{1} \cdot I^{2}_{1}}}$$

$$D = \frac{{I^{1}_{1} \cdot V^{2}_{2} + V^{1}_{2} \cdot I^{2}_{1}}}{{I^{1}_{1} \cdot V^{2}_{1} + V^{1}_{1} \cdot I^{2}_{1}}}$$